When I create custom permissions, After saving it automatically deleting the saved permissions in Django
In the Django admin class for the group creation page, I added additional fields. Based on these fields, I need to filter and set the permissions for the group. However, the issue arises in the save method. Although it saves the permissions, I noticed during debugging that the save_m2m() method in the superclass deletes all the assigned permissions
class CustomGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    env_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    schema_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['name', 'permissions', 'env_name', 'schema_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['permissions'].queryset = Permission.objects.none()
        

    def save(self, commit=True):
        group = super().save(commit=False)
        
        # Use the name field as the prefix to filter permissions
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name', '')
        prefix = name
        logger.info(f'Prefix 1: {prefix}')
        
        # Filter permissions using the prefix
        filtered_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(
            content_type__app_label__startswith=prefix
        )
        
        # Save the group first to ensure it has an ID
        group.save()
        
        # Set the filtered permissions
        group.permissions.set(filtered_permissions)
        
        if commit:
            group.save()

        return group

I expected the custom logic in the save method to correctly save the filtered permissions to the group without being overwritten. Specifically, I wanted the dynamically filtered permissions to persist after saving, without the save_m2m() method clearing them.
